# How to configure server-side authentication in CDO 3.0 or above?

Tags: eclipse, authentication, eclipse-emf, cdo-emf

Standalone CDO servers are configured using the [cdo-server.xml configuration file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDO_Server_Configuration_Reference), as explained on the CDO Wiki. A separate wiki page has further information about configuring server-side [CDO/Net4j authentication](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Use_CDO_Net4J_Authentification), but it is outdated as of version 3.0, as noted on the page:

> [...] Note that in CDO 3.0 we have an additional, superior athentication mechanism per CDOSession (not only on Net4j IConnector level). [...]

Neither new authentication mechanism, nor its usage are explained. How do I configure server-side authentication in CDO 3.0 or above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new authentication mechanism introduced in CDO 3.0 is configured using the `userManager` element in your cdo-server.xml, for example:

```
<repository name="MyRepo">
    <userManager type="file" description="absolute-path-to-users-file"/>  
    ...
</repository>
```

The above example is using the built-in `FileUserManager`, which has a factory registered with the type "file". This user manager implementation authenticates users against a list of usernames and passwords stored in a flat file at the location specified in the `description` attribute. This file should contain the users and their passwords in the following format:

```
user1:pwd1
user2:pwd2
```

Some background on implementing you own `UserManager` and how this configuration mechanism was implemented is available in the Eclipse Bugzilla issue [Allow configuration of authentication in cdo-server.xml](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=302775).